Methods to determine stability of open-loop systems
Which methods can be used to analyze the stability of open-loop systems only, closed-loop systems only, and both of them?
As far as I understand, you can determine the stability of open-loop and closed-loop systems by locating the poles of their respective Laplace transfer functions. However, when you use the Bode plot (frequency response) or the Nyquist criterion, you just use the open-loop transfer function to infer the stability of the closed-loop system. These methods are not applicable to the stability of the open-loop system itself. Furthermore, the Hurwitz criterion is used to analyze the stability of closed-loop systems.
So, is there no other way to determine the stability of an open-loop system besides locating the poles?

It appears you can use a Nyquist plot and just consider encirclements of the origin rather than -1.
My reasoning was to follow a similar mathematical derivation to that on the Wikipedia page for the Nyquist Stability Criterion, which I adapted as follows:
You want to determine the stability of the transfer function $H[s]$, thus you want to check whether there are any poles in the right half plane.
Suppose that we have a clockwise contour $C$ enclosing the right half plane, then Cauchy's argument principle states:
$$N=-\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_C\frac{H'[s]}{H[s]}ds=Z-P$$
Where $Z$ and $P$ are the number of zeros and poles of $H[s]$, respectively, enclosed by the contour. Making the substitution $w=H[s]$:
$$N=-\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_{H[s]}\frac{1}{w}dw$$
This contour is your Nyquist plot. Therefore:
$$P=Z-N$$
Where $N$ is the number of times the Nyquist plot encircles the origin clockwise.
The system is stable when $P\leq0$, which occurs when the number of zeros of $H[s]$ in the right half plane is less than or equal to the number of times the Nyquist plot encircles the origin clockwise.
I ran a few checks with some transfer functions I knew to be stable and unstable, and it looked like it works. For example, the figures below were generated using Matlab's nyquistplot function, with the left being $H[s]=\frac{1}{s^2-s+1}$, which is unstable and anticlockwise encircles the origin once so $P=1$, and the right being $H[s]=\frac{1}{s^2+s+1}$, which is stable and clockwise encircles the origin once so $P=-1$.
One of the challenges is that as frequency approaches infinity, for most, if not all, physical systems, the gain approaches zero as it simply cannot respond, for which the Nyquist plot will approach the origin, meaning it may not always be that clear.

I'm not a fan of using Bode plots to determine stability as my experience is they are much more limited, but I suppose you could extend this to them as well.
